# Easiest way to change default mirror of an Ubuntu ISO

Tags: ubuntu, mirror, iso

What is the easiest way to "patch" an Ubuntu ISO so that the default mirror is different?

Details:

- We're behind a proxy so upon initial installations, the process isn't able to the see the mirror
- We do have an internal mirror I'd like to point to
- I'm looking for something easy so that future ISOs can just be "patched" then burned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the details of the mirror and/or proxy in the [preseed file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization#Modify_installer_behaviour_using_a_Preseed_file).  All of the possible preseed values you can use should be provided in the manual for the Ubuntu version you're using, but the keys you're interested in are probably `mirror/http/proxy` and/or `mirror/http/hostname`.